# Brief Notification in Android 11 doesn't work

Tags: notifications, popup

Android 11 notifications pop-up style is either Brief or Detailed.. Detailed is the default pop-up style which we used to see before Android 11.. The new pop-up style in Android 11 is Brief which is unfortunately doesn't work with me.. any advice?